# How do I translate notes to MIDINoteNumber in AudioKit?

Tags: audiokit

In AudioKit, notes are identified by the MIDINoteNumber type, which is an alias for UInt8. How would I translate musical notes to MIDINoteNumber?

Comment: Middle C is 60, an octave up from that is 72 etc.  Googling 'MIDI note number' will give you literally dozens of charts which answer your question more precisely.